# Concept of bit field

Tags: c, bit-fields

```
struct A
{
 int a:2;
 int b:3;
 int c:3;
};

int main()
{
 struct A p = {2,6,1};
 printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",p.a,p.b,p.c);
 return 0;
}
```

Output is: 
    -2,-2,1

What would be output of above code in C complier and in C++ complier?
And Why?

Comment: Have a look here: http://ideone.com/o817J

Comment: Yes and answer was as per output.

Comment: bitfields are only well behaved for unsigned values (not sure if the behavior for a signed values is undefined or unspecified).

Comment: Why, it's the difference between `signed` and `unsigned` integers.  You *probably* want `unsigned`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, bitfields are perfectly well-defined for signed values.

Comment: It may be possible that it is using signed cycle rule. As followed by char when we give value as input to it , which is out of it's range.

Comment: It may be possible that it is using signed cycle rule. As followed by char when we give value as input to it , which is out of it's range. Example: if we give 128 as input to char a; and print value of 'a' then it will print -128 i.e. char range cycle -128 to 127. In similar fashion if we input 130 output would be -126.

Comment: @suraj.prasoon: If that was the case, then 6 should not have been interpreted correctly as -2 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Lets see what exactly is happening. Lets start with the given code:

```
struct A
{
 int a:3;
};
int main()
{
 struct A p = {5};
 printf("%d",p.a);
}
```

within 3 bits the values would be 101(5) since sign bit of this 3 bit set is 1 thus negative value. Thus we need to find 2's compliment of 101 which would be 011(3).
Thus by applying above logic we would output as -3. Similarly others could be proved.

e.g. for 1001(9) we shall take 3 bit values because of a:3. thus it would be 001(1). Since here sign bit is not set i.e. 1 so no need to use 2's complement. Straight forward answer would be 1.
Similarly others could be done.

Answer (score 5):

Your system seems to using [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). A `2-bit` bit-field holding `2` would be `10` in binary which is `-2` in 2's complement system. Likewise `110(6)` is `-2` for a `3-bit` representation in 2's complement. And `1` is plain `1`

Also read about signed bit-fields [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13991)

Answer (score 3):

I get -2 -2 1 with my C compiler. The problem is that your bit fields are too small for the numbers you are trying to store. In the first two cases, the leftmost bits are 1's, so they are interpreted as negative numbers. To fix this, either:

1. Make your bit fields larger
2. Declare your bit fields as unsigned ints instead of ints
3. Cast to unsigned int before printing and use %u to print.

Answer (score 1):

You get those answers for the same reason that this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    int32_t a = 4294967294;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Has output `-2`.  Initializing a signed variable with a number too large to fit causes it to be interpreted differently.  From the spec:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.