# print bit type as integer? How is the conversion?

Tags: c, bit

the program is :

```
typedef struct xp {
        int a:2;
        int b:2;
        int c:1;
} xp;

int main(void)
{
        xp x;
        memset(&x, 0, sizeof(xp));

        x.a = 1;
        x.b = 3;
        x.c = 1;

        printf("%d\n",x.a);
        printf("%d\n",x.b);
        printf("%d\n",x.c);

        return 0;
}
```

I get 1 -1 -1, why? How are a, b and c stored in x? What happened when printf("%d\n",x.a); is executed?

Comment: This is a duplicate; I know I answered exactly this question once before.  I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: Until Carl finds the dupe: because your compiler interprets the bit-fields as two's-complement numbers.

Comment: It's actually implementation-defined whether they're signed or unsigned.

Comment: Found it: [Concept of bit field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320731/concept-of-bit-field)

Comment: Note that 1-bit signed bitfields aren't specified to be able to hold any value at all!

Comment: @Neil: They can always hold the value 0 and some other value.

Comment: @KeithThompson, that other value could be a "negative zero" :) fortunately nobody does these things anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a signed type for your bitfields, which means you've created what amounts to two two-bit signed integers, and one one-bit signed integer.

The possible values for a two-bit signed integer (two's complement) are: -2, -1, 0, and 1:

The possible values for a one-bit signed integer (two's complement) are -1 and 0.

By storing values that "don't fit", like you have done in these lines:

```
x.b = 3;
x.c = 1;
```

You will get strange behaviour as the bit patterns you store are interpreted differently when read.  You can have a similar experience by doing something like:

```
char x = 58147;
```

on a machine with an 8-bit `char` type, that value won't fit, so you'll read something different back when accessing `x`.

Comment: @ccsnailpp, it's -1 because it's two's-complement.  The leading bit is a 1, so that means it's a negative number.  To translate to the corresponding positive number, do `~x + 1`.  In this case that's `~11 + 1 = 00 + 1 = 1`.  In two's complement, an all-ones bit pattern always represents -1.

Answer (score 2):

A bit field of type `int` is either of type `signed int` or of type `unsigned int`. The choice is implementation-defined.  This is for historical reasons.  This is the only context in which `int` and `signed int` can differ.

This is specified in section 6.7.2 of the C standard ([C99 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), [C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), following a list of type specifiers:

> Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except
>   that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the
>   specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type
>   as `unsigned int`.

The solution is to avoid using plain `int` for bit fields; always declare them either as `signed int` or as `unsigned int`.  (The latter almost always makes more sense.)