# uint8_t data types initialisation

Tags: c

Recently I stumbled upon a code written like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t TC0_WG0     :2;
  uint8_t TC0_CS      :3;
} Timer0;
```

What I wanted to know is what does the part that says `:2;` & `:3;` specifically mean? Is it accessing the bits 0, 1, 2 only or 0, 1, 2 & 3 only of the 8-bit unsigned character or what ?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933242/when-to-use-bit-fields-in-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320731/concept-of-bit-field

Comment: This is not standard C code, but an extension. So it can mean whatever your compiler says it will mean.

Comment: "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted."

Answer (score 1):

These are basically bitfields explicitly telling that the `TC0_CS` would be in 3 bit.

These can be used to save space. In embedded system, I have faced this use when designing an interrupt system. Used bitfield to specify the specific positions as a way to activate deactivate interrupts.

He is not accessing the 0,1 or 2nd bits but OP can using appropriate bit masking.

Comment: thanks man I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

It is called **bit-field members**.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field) say's :

**Bit fields**

> Declares a member with explicit width, in bits. Adjacent bit field
>   members may be packed to share and straddle the individual bytes.
>
> A bit field declaration is a struct or union member declaration which
>   uses the following declarator:
>
> ```
> identifier(optional) : width
> ```
>
> **identifier**    -   the name of the bit field that is being declared. The name is optional: nameless bitfields introduce the specified number of
>   bits of padding
>
> **width** -   an integer constant expression with a value greater or equal to zero and less or equal the number of bits in the underlying
>   type. When greater than zero, this is the number of bits that this bit
>   field will occupy. The value zero is only allowed for nameless
>   bitfields and has special meaning: it specifies that the next bit
>   field in the class definition will begin at an allocation unit's
>   boundary.